# Help with PN512 basic PCB antenna design

Tags: pcb-design, nfc, pcb-antenna

I'm designing a small board that integrate a PN512 IC along with other components (MCU, etc). I need to build a proof-of-concept device for a presentation with the ***suit people*** and everything is ready but the PN512 antenna/matching circuit design. My guidelines for a PCB antenna are:

1. It must be single layer. (I've seen single layer designs with a 0 ohm resistor as a jumper over the traces)
2. It can't be more than 10x10cm or 4x4in.
3. I need it to successfully transmit data between the PN512 and an external NFC device, 5cm (2 in) or less range will be more than fine.
4. I own a 200MHz scope to play with (Sadly, no network analyzer).
5. My knowledge of the "black magic" behind this is very limited, but I'm learning as i go.

So my question is:

**It is possible to build an antenna with the above requirements? Do you know of any (open) design available to get as starting point?**

I've found **many** design guides for 2.4GHz antennas, but nothing helpful for the 13.56MHz range. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Datasheet for the *suit people* would be amusing to see :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [this document](http://eng.utah.edu/~mlewis/ref/NFC/AN1445.pdf) about antenna design for the PN512? The rectangular antenna on page 47 looks like it will meet your needs.

Texas instruments also makes some fairly decent [HF antenna](http://www.ti.com/rfid/docs/manuals/appNotes/HFAntennaDesignNotes.pdf) [design guides](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa135/sloa135.pdf).

I've fabricated some of these rectangular antennas for 13.56MHz NFC before (the ones specified by TI), they're fairly simple and work well as can be expected.

Comment: +1 for app note. Cool! Nice find.

Answer (score 2):

## Context

I could give you all the math and physics, but I think you just want the "do this" answer, so here goes:

The NFC part of your design problem relaxes a number of the usual antenna design requirements since it is "near-field" (the NF in NFC). From an end-user performance metric (can it read/write the tag), it isn't super sensitive to the impedances and the antenna impedances don't change a lot given the small-scale and close proximity. Basically, it's all bad, so a little more or less bad doesn't matter a lot. NFC was designed to discourage long-range reading (snooping).

## Solution

Follow the Philips (NXP) reference design for the front-end and then draft an antenna something like:

- 2" x 2" loop
- with a few turns (say 4)
- with as filamentary a conductor as possible (your PCB fabricator's minimum track width)
- with minimum gap between turns (your PCB fabricator's minimum gap width)

## Implementation

- To minimize cross-overs, spiral inwards.
- Obviously, ensure that there is no metal near the loop and specifically inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can find all your answers in Panasonic's design tool, which also offers a simulation of the distance that you can achieve.
https://b2bsol.panasonic.biz/semi-spt/apl/en/tool/nfcdesignnavigator/

Additional resources can be found from NXP, Nordic Semiconductors and Texas Instruments.
Search for Nordic's appnote called "nwp_026 NFC Tuning", that will give you an insight of what equipment you might need. 
I have recently got to work an NFC tag, just using the math calculations from that app note, even without the equipment, and it matched the distance simulated in Panasonic's tool.